# Auto import scala libraries in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick

I am going through slick tutorial at the moment, I stumble upon issue with importing slick libraries. I have the following class:

```
// A Suppliers table with 6 columns: id, name, street, city, state, zip
class Suppliers(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {

  // This is the primary key column:
  def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street = column[String]("STREET")
  def city = column[String]("CITY")
  def state = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip = column[String]("ZIP")

  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)] = (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}
```

simple copy paste from http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html
Now i have to import "not resolved symbols" like `Tag, Table, column`. Unfortunately intellij does not suggest the proper one (which must be added manually - `slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._`).  I remember I had similar issues with gatling, which for person starting playing with framework/tool and not knowing exact packages is quite time consuming.

Is there a way to make intellij suggest all possible imports?

I have Intellij IDEA 2016.3.2 with scala plugin 2016.3.5 installed

Comment: I don't know how would you do that but you simply need to add only one import - `slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._`. Doesn't seem like to much of work... Also keep in mind that its dependent on DB you use (some other person may need to add e.g. `slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._` )

Comment: Yes, that true, once you know it. When i copied all the code, I got  I started importing classes, for Table intellij suggested `org.h2.table.Table` and `slick.model.Table`, as it is slick framework i tried second and later first one, with no luck (as it was supposed to be `slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._`). Whats more the for the column intellij did not suggest anything (however there is one slick.model.Column - but with capital C, another dead end). I see the point that it can depend on the DB, but i would expect is that IDE will show me all the available `Profiles`